# jQuery: .live() and .on() - live returns this as JS object, on return this as jQuery object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

I want to replace an old `.live()` function with `.on()`.

**.live()**

```
 var jqRow = $('#' + id + ' tr');
 jqRow.live("click", function () {
            myFunction(this);
            return false;
        });
```

**.on()**

```
var jqRow = $('#' + id + ' tr');
$(document).on("click", jqRow, function () {
                    myFunction(this);
                    return false;
        });
```

The `this` of the `.live()` method returns a JS object (I need this).
The `this` of the `.on()` method returns a jQuery object, that causes myFunction to fail.

How can I get the same non jQuery this object like in the live function?

Comment: Are you positive that `this` is a jQuery object? `this` in JavaScript is immutable so it cannot possibly be set to a jQuery object, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @JackFranklin this can have different values depending on how function is called for example.

Comment: I have been tested this script and `console.log(this)` returns an JS `document` object, not jQuery object

Comment: I understand that, but I didn't think it was possible to set it to a jQuery object, as `this` is always set based on the scope in which the function was invoked.

@Keith L, could you put an example on JSFiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, your `jqRow` variable is a jQuery object, but the `.on()` function only takes **string selectors**. If you pass a jQuery object, that argument is ignored, and it's the same as setting up a non-delegated event handler on the document itself.

Change this:

```
var jqRow = $('#' + id + ' tr'); // this line creates a jQuery object
$(document).on("click", jqRow, function () {
    myFunction(this);
    return false;
});
```

to this:

```
var jqRow = '#' + id + ' tr'; // this line initialises a string
$(document).on("click", jqRow, function () {
    myFunction(this);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Not true, `on()` can take a jQuery selector as the second argument. See: http://jsfiddle.net/2W8pM/

Comment: @JackFranklin Using `e.target` isn't the same as using `this`, your jsFiddle is meaningless. Take a look at [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/2W8pM/1/), that actually matches the code in the question.

Comment: @JackFranklin To make that clearer: when you pass anything other than a string as an argument, it's ignored (because it's invalid) and you get a direct event handler attached to the `document` for `click` events. jQuery will make `this` the document itself, but `e.target` will be the element that was originally clicked on and caused the event to propagate up the DOM all the way to the document.

Comment: Anthony, my apologies, I misread. You are indeed correct, have amended my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If `this` is *really* a jQuery object, you can use `this[0]` or [`this.get(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

> The `.get()` method grants us access to the DOM nodes underlying each jQuery object.

Answer (score 3):

Following on from my comment, it's **not** possible for `this` to be a jQuery object. This is because the value of `this` within a function is set when the function is invoked, and cannot explicitly be set, it's immutable. It *is* possible for `$(this)` to be a jQuery object though, obviously.

**EDIT**

As @Anthony Grist pointed out, the real issue here is using a jQuery selector in `.on()`. If you change it to pass in a string selector, the value of `this` is set accordingly. My apologies for the oversight, here's a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2W8pM/3/).

For what it's worth, if you're delegating to a single selector, I would just call `.on()` on that selector:

```
$("#foo").on("click", function() {});
```

Otherwise...

If you're unable to pass in the string selector and have to pass in an actual jQuery object, you can work around it using the event object. This code works:

```
var jqRow = $('#foo');
$(document).on("click", jqRow, function (e) {
  myFunction(e.target);
  return false;
});

var jqRow2 = $('#bar');
jqRow2.live("click", function () {
  myFunction(this);
  return false;
 });


function myFunction(x) {
  console.log(x);
  console.log($(x).attr("id"));
}
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2W8pM/)

Remember, with the syntax you're using there for delegating does **not** bind an event to `jqRow`, it binds it to the `document`. jQuery doesn't let you pass in a jQuery object as to be delegated to. So the first part of the above code is fairly pointless, you could just do:

```
var jqRow = $('#foo');
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
  if($(e.target).attr("id") === "foo") {
    myFunction(e.target);
  }
  return false;
});
```

This is why the value of `this` within your `.on()` is not the object clicked, as you expected as jQuery can't delegate the event to a jQuery object, it needs a selector. So passing in `e.target` should fix your issue.

Comment: That's incorrect - `this` will be the element that was actually clicked on *provided* you correctly use `.on()` - passing a jQuery object is invalid. Using `e.target` is a workaround for not knowing how to actually use jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

you can use get() function, which takes index as parameter or you can use [].

```
var jqRow = $('#' + id + ' tr');
$(document).on("click", jqRow, function () {
                    myFunction(this.get(0));
                    // or this myFunction(this[0]);
                    return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    var id="" ;  // ID of your Element
     var jqRow = $('#' + id);
      jqRow.on("click", 'tr', function ()
      {
                //alert($(this));
                myFunction($(this));
                return false;
       });


 });​
```

​